# Resolve composite object name on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing node.js module and can't find how to resolve dynamically composite object names.
Say i have an object like: 
`application.config`
and i want to change some of its properties:

```
application.config.somename = "smth"
```

the problem is that anything that comes after `application.config` isn't known in advance, (it comes from browser)

The depth of the object isn't also known in advance it could be `application.config.somename.anothername` of course `somename` and `anothername` are defined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a module such as [dotty](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty). This lets you use an object path as a string for setting and getting values and checking for existence.

Comment: +1 for that (though don't have enough reputation) but what if one of the properties is array dotty can't resolve application.config.x[0].y

Comment: Currently you can check if `put(...) === false` to know if the object path is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If `application.config` is defined, `application.config.x` will work fine. You can add arbitrary attributes to an object at any time.

Comment: but depth isn't known also it can be application.config.x or application.config.x.y.z and x.y.z part comes as string